# The given type IControllerFactory is not a concrete type. Please use one of the other overloads to register this type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I use SimpleInjector 3.1.2 for constructor dependency injection.

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // dependency injection
    container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
    container.RegisterProviders();
    container.Verify();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

and **DependencyInjection.cs**

```
public static Container RegisterProviders(this Container container)
{
    container.Register<IAccountClosureProvider, AccountClosureProvider>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    container.Register<IActivityProvider, ActivityProvider>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    ... and more ...

    return container;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following exception:

**Exception details**

> A first chance exception of type 'SimpleInjector.ActivationException' occurred in SimpleInjector.dll
>
> The given type IControllerFactory is not a concrete type. Please use one of the other overloads to register this type.

Stacktrace:

```
at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultConstructorResolutionBehavior.VerifyTypeIsConcrete(Type implementationType)
```

Any ideas what's the problem here?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like it is having trouble resolving `IControllerFactory` does simpleinjector have a method for seeing what is registered in the container?

Answer (score 2):

You should register the controllers, this is done using the integration package for your project.

For MVC use: `SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc` and wire it up with:

```
container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

For Web API use: `SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi` and wire it up with:

```
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

For ASP.NET Core follow the [integration guide here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html).

Answer (score 0):

The message says:

> A first chance exception

This means that Visual Studio paused execution for an exception that is caught higher up the call stack. You should typically change Visual Studio's configuration to prevent getting these messages, because they are false positives. In case you hit F5, your program will continue running without any problem. For more information about first chance exceptions, please read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidklinems/2005/07/12/what-is-a-first-chance-exception/).

Note that we made some internal improvements in Simple Injector 3.2 and you'll see much less of those first chance exceptions in that release. I can advice you to upgrade to 3.2 as well.